# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'has'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery's `has` method in one of my menus to check whether the current `<li>` has any `<ul>` in it. If yes, then show them, or else hide the `li`.

But when using `has` I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'has'

My code:

```
$('nav ul li').click(function () {
    console.log(this.has('ul')); //Checking
    if ($(this).children('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp(250);
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown(250);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using a jQuery version < 1.4 ?

Comment: `has` is a jquery method but you're calling it on a DOM element.

Comment: Should be console.log($(this).has('ul'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you do `$(this)` later is because `this` is not a jQuery object. You still need to do `$(this).has('ul')`.

Note that you can also simplify the toggling part with `$(this).children('ul').slideToggle(250);`.